# Fetch all links on a page within css selector 'a' for each class 'r'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium in python to scrape all of the relevant URLS from a google search.

I understand that if I would like to have a list of URLs within the same class I can do the following:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('r')
name = div.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
```

What I would actually like is the url within a href for each class 'r' on the google page. I tried this:

```
div = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('r')
name = div.find_element_by_css_selector('a')
```

But I get this error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'`

How can I iterate through the classes and pull a single URL?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name` returns a list of web elements as opposed to a singular object of type `WebElement`. Maybe try the following:

```
for div in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a .r'):
    print(div.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_class_name` will return list of `elements` and list item does not have `.find_element_by_css_selector` object implement. So you are getting that message.

If you want to get the link item for each of the div then update your code as below.

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('r')
for div in divs:
    href= div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
```

You can use the xpath as shown below

```
links= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='r']//a[h3]")
for link in links:
    href= link.get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be also aware that in Selenium *4*, `find_elements_by_css_selector` was deprecated, so the new syntax is:

```
for div in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a .r'):
    print(div.get_attribute('href'))
```

Don't forget the import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```